# How can OS X cron use existing ssh-agent without environment?

Tags: macos, ssh, cron

I've looked all over these forums, and either haven't found an answer to this, or more frequently, the question is different.

Client is OS X El Capitan. I am logged in, and my ssh key (*with passphrase*) is properly stored in the keychain. Everything works fine manually: I can ssh to my server, where I've previously stored my public key, without being prompted for the passphrase. OS X loads it into the ssh-agent on login.

But of course my script to ssh to my server does not work in my account's cron, because the environment doesn't have the SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable. I get asked for the passphrase.

I am able to get it to work unattended like this:

```
my $sock = `ls /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.*/Listeners`; chomp($sock);
system("SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$sock  /usr/bin/ssh myhost mycommand") && die "blah: $!";
```

But this seems like a gross hack. The keychain is difficult to access, but has the potential to be really sweet. I can't imagine there's NO clean way to access it.

Comment: Usually, there is a problem with users. If you run `cron` under different user, it should not be able to operate with your user keychain. If you run the `cron` under the same user, then the above is quite valid workaround. `ssh-agent` concept is based on session-wide reach and therefore the connection is stored in environment variable. There is no other way to get this connection, than getting hold of the environment variable or the socket.

Comment: Fair enough. Same user in this case. I wouldn't try to do it otherwise. It just seemed that if Apple is going to wrap it all up so nicely (and it IS nice), they should go one more step and have a command line tool to get the socket, instead of having to grep for it. In fact, I recall reading the whole business is lazy init via launchd, so it's possible I could boot, login, and not have needed to init yet, so no socket. That missing CLI could have done the init, too. Oh well. I just hate the idea of globbing in a /tmp dir for chrissakes. But I guess it will continue to work. Thx.

Comment: Maybe there is some Apple command (I am not aware of, I don't use Apple, but on [AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com/), they might know).

Comment: Good idea. I asked here first (and I was tempted to use ServerFault) because it's terminal / networking stuff, and nothing to do with the UI, but I'll give it a shot. What's the protocol here? Can I just open a Q there with a link to this Q? Duplicate it?